# Does putting images in folder references still allow @2x and @3x optimizations?

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

In Xcode asset catalogs, each image asset has slots for normal size, @2x, and @3x images that Xcode uses to bundle the proper asset for a given device resolution.

Do you get that same benefit if you put @2x and @3x assets into a folder reference in the app bundle? (In Xcode UI, these show up as blue folders, but the @2x and @3x images show up as separate images.)

[image] 
Folder Reference in Xcode Containing @2x and @3x Images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don’t get the same benefits. You should use asset catalogs.

See [QA1795](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1795/_index.html), which mentions:

> Asset Catalogs help maximize the size reduction provided by App Slicing, which can be significant for apps with assets not needed by every device.

If you want a folder structure, you could put a separate asset catalog in each folder.

There are other benefits of asset catalogs as well, like image slicing, on-demand resource tags, and customizable compression options.

Worth watching the [app thinning WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=404) as well.

Comment: Got it, thanks for confirming! I do appreciate the thinning benefits but was leaning toward folder references because I want to use some of these images for stickers (iMessage extension) and alternate app icons, which don't seem possible from asset catalogs..